# C# distinguish between user form close and o.s. form close

Tags: c#, forms, shutdown, formclosing

I would like to know how to distinguish a form close between the user request and o.s. request (for example for a system shutdown). In the first case I want to ask exit confirmation, in the second I will exit without any other confirm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [event args](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.formclosingeventargs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for the FormClosing event has a CloseReason property which exposes a [CloseReason Enumerable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.closereason%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) value. This should tell you why the form is closing.

If the system is shutting down, it will contain the `WindowsShutDown` value.

If the user is closing the form by clicking the "x" button, then it will contain the `UserClosing` value.

Note that if you personally call the `Form.Close()` method from any method or event, it will likely have the `None` value, so if you are programatically closing your form via an event on an additional close button that you've added or after some action has been performed, you may have to handle that as well.

Answer (score 1):

Every form in its FormClosing event receives a `FormClosingEventArgs` where there are two properties named Cancel and [CloseReason](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.closereason%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

The first one allows to stop the closing of the form, the second one is an enum that defines a `WindowsShutDown` reason, so your code colud be

```
private void form_FormClosing(Object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e) 
{
   if(e.CloseReason != CloseReason.WindowsShutdown)
   {
      DialogResult d = MessageBox.Show("Closing app?", "MyApp", MessageBoxButton.YesNo );
      if(d == DialogResult.No)
         e.Cancel = true;
   }
}
```